# Upgrading to Photos errors "Library Version Too Old" and "Your library can open. . . "

Tags: macos, photos, upgrade, photos.app

My iPhoto app, version 9.2.1, has a grey icon with a no sign and won't open.  I'm running OSX 10.10.5, and I noticed a new app called Photos (version 1.0.1).  When I try to open Photos, I am prompted to choose my single iPhoto library to convert to Photos.  But when I click "choose library", I get the error

> **Library Version Too Old** Please upgrade your library “iPhoto Library” using the free iPhoto Library Upgrader available from Apple.

Okay.  So I download the library upgrader (v. 1.1) and follow the instructions.  It claims

> Your library can open with the current version of iPhoto and does not need to be prepared with this tool.

Turns out this tool is designed to prepared libraries from iPhoto 7 and earlier, so it's not surprising that it doesn't work with my deprecated 9.2.1 iPhoto.  But it's the only application I can find that matches Photos' description of an "iPhoto Library Upgrader".

How can I import my photos into Photos, given this circle of errors?  Many thanks for any clues!

Comment: Last iPhoto was 9.6.1, Photos is currently at 1.5. Have you tried updating either or both & see what happens? idk why iPhoto would be greyed out, btw. Mine still works on El Capitan, even though I swapped to Photos over a year ago